# Bootstrap columns overlapping over one another on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Firstly, here's a JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y9bp4oat/

I'm currently using bootstrap's grid system to display a bunch of items in rows of 4. When you hover over an item it'll flip to the back and display more details. It works great, problem comes when there's an item directly below the item you're currently hovering over, the item below blocks or overlays itself on the item that's being hovered. I'm sorry if my explanation is confusing, the JSFiddle demo will let you see what I mean.

I've been trying to fix this issue with z-index, making sure the position isn't set to default but to no avail. I've  been trying to fix this issue for days now. Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 pull-left mb-3">                          
            <div class="flip-container">               
                <div class="flipper"> 
                    <div class="front bg-dark">
                    </div>                              
                    <div class="back">                                   
                        <div class="bg-dark mystyle text-center py-3" >
                            <h5>Restaurant</h5>
                            <h5>10 Reviews<h5>
                            <h5>Average Rating: 4.5/5 </h5>
                            <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">SeeMore</button>                     
                            <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reviews</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 pull-left mb-3">                          
            <div class="flip-container">               
                <div class="flipper"> 
                    <div class="front bg-dark">
                    </div>                              
                    <div class="back">                                   
                        <div class="bg-dark mystyle text-center py-3" >
                            <h5>Restaurant</h5>
                            <h5>10 Reviews<h5>
                            <h5>Average Rating: 4.5/5 </h5>
                            <button href="#"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">See More</button>                     
                            <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reviews</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 pull-left mb-3">                          
            <div class="flip-container">               
                <div class="flipper"> 
                    <div class="front bg-dark">
                    </div>                              
                    <div class="back">                                   
                        <div class="bg-dark mystyle text-center py-3" >
                            <h5>Restaurant</h5>
                            <h5>10 Reviews<h5>
                            <h5>Average Rating: 4.5/5 </h5>
                            <button href="#"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">See More</button>                     
                            <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reviews</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 pull-left mb-3">                          
            <div class="flip-container">               
                <div class="flipper"> 
                    <div class="front bg-dark">
                    </div>                              
                    <div class="back">                                   
                        <div class="bg-dark mystyle text-center py-3" >
                            <h5>Restaurant</h5>
                            <h5>10 Reviews<h5>
                            <h5>Average Rating: 4.5/5 </h5>
                            <button href="#"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">See 
                            More</button>                     
                            <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn 
                            sm">Reviews</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 pull-left mb-3">                          
            <div class="flip-container">               
                <div class="flipper"> 
                    <div class="front bg-dark">
                    </div>                              
                    <div class="back">                                   
                        <div class="bg-dark mystyle text-center py-3" >
                            <h5>Restaurant</h5>
                            <h5>10 Reviews<h5>
                            <h5>Average Rating: 4.5/5 </h5>
                            <button href="#"  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">See More</button>                     
                            <button href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reviews</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.mystyle{
height: 90px;
width: 254px;
color: white;
font-size: smaller;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 10px;
margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
float: left;
position: relative;
transition: 1s;
-webkit-transition: 1s; 
text-align: left;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
z-index: 5;
}

.flip-container{
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper ,
.flip-container.hover .flipper{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

.flip-container:hover .flipper .mystyle,
.flip-container.hover .flipper .mystyle{
    height: 150px;
    width: 254px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;    
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back{
    height: 100px;
    width: 254px;
}
.flipper{
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.front,
.back{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;   

}
.front{
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the z-index at the outer container:

```
.flip-container:hover{
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/r62wxp4L/3/